# How to find n as sum of dustinct prime numbers (when n is even number)

Tags: functional-programming

This problem gives you a positive integer number which is less than or equal to 100000 (10^5). You have to find out the following things for the number:

i. Is the number prime number? If it is a prime number, then print YES.

ii. If the number is not a prime number, then can we express the number as summation of unique prime numbers? If it is possible, then print YES. Here unique means, you can use any prime number only for one time.

If above two conditions fail for any integer number, then print NO. For more clarification please see the input, output section and their explanations.

Input
At first you are given an integer T (T<=100), which is the number of test cases. For each case you will be given a positive integer X which is less than or equal 100000.

Output
For every test case, print only YES or NO.

Sample
Input   Output
3
7
6
10  YES
NO
YES
Case – 1 Explanation: 7 is a prime number.

Case – 2 Explanation: 6 is not a prime number. 6 can be expressed as 6 = 3 + 3 or 6 = 2 + 2 + 2. But you can’t use any prime number more than 1 time. Also there is no way to express 6 as two or three unique prime numbers summation.

Case – 3 Explanation: 10 is not prime number but 10 can be expressed as 10 = 3 + 7 or 10 = 2 + 3 + 5. In this two expressions, every prime number is used only for one time.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking for a hint for solving it efficiently, an algorithm which runs in reasonable time, a C++ implementation, or how to resolve a compile error in your code?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Looks like a (homework / competition) problem dump. Any thoughts / attempts of your own?

Comment: Yes i was asking for a short time code... I was making an O(3) of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without employing any mathematical tricks (not sure if any exist...you'd think as a mathematician I'd have more insight here), you will have to iterate over every possible summation. Hence, you'll definitely need to iterate over every possible prime, so I'd recommend the first step being to find all the primes at most 10^5. A basic (Sieve of Eratosthenes)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes] will probably be good enough, though faster sieves exist nowadays. I know your question is language agnostic, but you could consider the following as vectorized pseudocode for such a sieve.

```
import numpy as np

def sieve(n):
    index = np.ones(n+1, dtype=bool)
    index[:2] = False
    for i in range(2, int(np.sqrt(n))):
        if index[i]:
            index[i**2::i] = False
    return np.where(index)[0]
```

There are some other easy optimizations, but for simplicity this assumes that we have an array `index` where the indices correspond exactly to whether the number is prime or not. We start with every number being prime, mark 0 and 1 as not prime, and then for every prime we find we mark every multiple of it as not prime. The `np.where()` at the end just returns the indices where our index corresponds to `True`.

From there, we can consider a recursive algorithm for actually solving your problem. Note that you might feasibly have a huge number of distinct primes necessary. The number 26 is the sum of 4 distinct primes. It is also the sum of 3 and 23. Since the checks are more expensive for 4 primes than for 2, I think it's reasonable to start by checking the smallest number possible.

In this case, the way we're going to do that is to define an auxiliary function to find whether a number is the sum of precisely k primes and then sequentially test that auxiliary function for k from 1 to whatever the maximum possible number of addends is.

```
primes = sieve(10**5)

def sum_of_k_primes(x, k, excludes=()):
    if k == 1:
        if x not in excludes and x in primes:
            return (x,)+excludes
        else:
            return ()
    for p in (p for p in primes if p not in excludes):
        if x-p < 2:
            break
        temp = sum_of_k_primes(x-p, k-1, (p,)+excludes)
        if temp:
            return temp
    return ()
```

Running through this, first we check the case where `k` is 1 (this being the base case for our recursion). That's the same as asking if `x` is prime and isn't in one of the primes we've already found (the tuple `excludes`, since you need uniqueness). If `k` is at least 2, the rest of the code executes instead. We check all the primes we might care about, stopping early if we'd get an impossible result (no primes in our list are less than 2). We recursively call the same function for smaller `k`, and if we succeed we propagate that result up the call stack.

Note that we're actually returning the smallest possible tuple of unique prime addends. This is empty if you want your answer to be `"NO"` as specified, but otherwise it allows you to easily come up with an explanation for why you answered `"YES"`.

```
partial = np.cumsum(primes)

def max_primes(x):
    return np.argmax(partial > x)

def sum_of_primes(x):
    for k in range(1, max_primes(x)+1):
        temp = sum_of_k_primes(x, k)
        if temp:
            return temp
    return ()
```

For the rest of the code, we store the partial sums of all the primes up to a given point (e.g. with primes 2, 3, 5 the partial sums would be 2, 5, 10). This gives us an easy way to check what the maximum possible number of addends is. The function just sequentially checks if `x` is prime, if it is a sum of 2 primes, 3 primes, etc....

As some example output, we have

```
>>> sum_of_primes(1001)
(991, 7, 3)

>>> sum_of_primes(26)
(23, 3)

>>> sum_of_primes(27)
(19, 5, 3)

>>> sum_of_primes(6)
()
```

At a first glance, I thought caching some intermediate values might help, but I'm not convinced that the auxiliary function would ever be called with the same arguments twice. There might be a way to use dynamic programming to do roughly the same thing but in a table with a minimum number of computations to prevent any duplicated efforts with the recursion. I'd have to think more about it.

As far as the exact output your teacher is expecting and the language this needs to be coded in, that'll be up to you. Hopefully this helps on the algorithmic side of things a little.